# Errors everywhere when uncommenting JavaScriptSerializer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, visual-studio-debugging

My solution has 4 projects; one of the projects is a class library (dll) called `HelperClass`.  Within `HelperClass`, there's a class called `Conversions`with static method `public static System.IO.Stream ConvertToJson(DataTable)`

Within this static method, I  instantiate with `JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();`. When I uncomment that line, all calls from all projects that reference the HelperClass library immediately break; the project is not recognized. I comment it back and everything returns to normal.

Even though it turns out that I didn't have to use `JavaScriptSerializer`, I would still like to know why this happens.

I've read to change the project target framework to `.NET Framework 4 - Client Profile`. With all the warnings I get, I ended up not doing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all your projects are set to the full .net profile not Client. Right click the projects and click properties it the dropdown on the first page.